# Windows 10: English Igbo keyboard appeared in the Language bar after Outlook Mail client setup?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

Everyone,

I have set up the default Mail app in Windows 10, however, directly afterwards a new language was added to the Language bar (as per the below screenshot):

[ENG IG keyboard layout is not needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/547o3.png)

The problem is: I am unable to delete this newly added language (English: Igbo keyboard) by any means. Do you have any advice how it can be removed?

Answer (score 0):

After a restart the extra keyboard layout disappeared, most probably it appeared only once due to the default Mail configuration.